# Firestore - Update an array of type DocumentReference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore as a quasi-relational database for a side project. In the Console GUI, I can create an array of `DocumentReference`s, and then use the values in that array to load child components when needed. I would like to do the same in my code but am unable to.

I have tried:

```
constructor(private store: AngularFirestore) {}

this.store
  .collection('owners')
  .doc(this.owner.id)
  .update({
    trucks: [
      ...this.owner.trucks, // firestore array of references
      this.store.doc(`/truck/${documentReference.id}`),
    ],
  });
```

But that stores the value as a `string` in Firestore.

Is there a way to store the value as an instance of `DocumentReference`?

Comment: What is your Firebase SDK version (and what is `this.store` here)? Also can you share a screenshot showing that it's a string if the following doesn't work?

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show a *complete* example that doesn't work the way you expect.  We can't see `this.store` nor `this.owner.trucks` so we don't really know what this code is actually doing.  We should be able to copy your code and run it easily for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayUnion()` if you want to push a new element to an array in Firestore document instead of fetching existing values first as shown below:

```
import { arrayUnion } from "firebase/firestore";

// ...

this.store
  .collection('owners')
  .doc(this.owner.id)
  .update({
    trucks: arrayUnion(this.store.doc(`/truck/${documentReference.id}`),
  });
```

The value should be a `DocumentReference` if you pass the result of `doc()` directly in either of the code snippets. Can you confirm it by hovering on the field? It should show the type.

[image]